# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on line 118, but it does take the user value from the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am taking the exciting running and tested code with different database. I am able to connect to the database and the file did take user id from the database but when I click on button "click here to begin" nothing happens no error log entry was generated. just the Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when inspect (ctrl + shift + i) the file.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php
 require("db.php");

 $userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $_GET["user_id"]);
 
 $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `t01_users` where `a01_userid` = '. $userid.' ";
 $result =  mysqli_query($db_connection, $strSQL) or die(mysqli_error($db_connection));
 if (!$result) {
   echo("<p>Error performing query: " . mysqli_error($db_connection) . "</p>");
   exit();
 }

 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 

?>
<head>
<title>TEST YOUR KNOWLEDGE</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<div>
    <div>
        <h1 class="text-center">TEST YOUR KNOWLEDGE</h1>
<!-- display course title -->
        <p class="text-center" id="course_title">Test quiz</p>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
<!-- display quiz score -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
        <span id="your_score"> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- quiz part -->
    <div id="quiz_part">

        <div>
        <img src="images/cubic.png">
        </div>

        <div>
        <p class="text-center">This quiz contains <span id="number_of_question">8</span> questions.<br>
        <span class="text-center">
        You need to achieve a score of at least <span id="pass_percentage">80</span>% to complete the course.</span>
        </p>
        </div>

        <div class="text-center">
            <button id="start_quiz">CLICK HERE TO BEGIN</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-right" id="submit_button_div">

    </div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="no_check" title="Invalid answer" style="font-family:Calibri;">Please select an answer before submitting.</div>

<div id="correct" title="This is correct." class="dialog">
    <div class="correct_content" style="font-family:Calibri;"></div>
</div>
<div id="incorrect" title="This is incorrect." class="dialog">
    <div class="incorrect_content" style="font-family:Calibri;"></div>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var screenWidth, dialogWidth;

    screenWidth = window.screen.width;
    

    if ( screenWidth < 500 ) {
        dialogWidth = screenWidth * .95;
        
    } else {
        dialogWidth = 500;
    }


    var userid = <?php echo $userid ; ?>; 
    
    var flag = 0;        
    var score = 0;
    var current_question_number = 0;
    var current_question = "";

    var course_title = "";
    var number_of_question = 0;
    var pass_percentage = 0;
    var progress_url = "";

    var pass_remark = "";
    var failed_remark = "";

    var questions = new Array();

    $( "#no_check" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });

    $.getJSON( "questions.json", function(data) {
    // note: this getJSON access the file asynchronously. must set value inside the block
        course_title = data.course_title;
        $("#course_title").html(course_title);
        number_of_question = data.number_of_question;
        $("#number_of_question").html(number_of_question);
        pass_percentage = data.pass_percentage;
        $("#pass_percentage").html(pass_percentage);
        progress_url = data.progress_url

        //alert(progress_url);

        pass_remark = data.pass_remark;
        failed_remark = data.failed_remark;

        for(i=0; i<data.question_list.length; i++){
          questions[i]=new Array;
          questions[i]["question_number"] = data.question_list[i].question_number;
          questions[i]["annotation"] = data.question_list[i].annotation;
          questions[i]["question"] = data.question_list[i].question;
          questions[i]["type"] = data.question_list[i].type;
          questions[i]["instruction"] = data.question_list[i].instruction;
          choice = new Array();
          for (j=0; j<data.question_list[i].choice.length; j++){
            var option = new Array();
            option["label"] = data.question_list[i].choice[j].label;
            //alert(data.question_list[i].choice[j].label);
            option["option"] = data.question_list[i].choice[j].option;
            choice[j] = option;
          }
          questions[i]["choice"] = choice;
          questions[i]["answer"] = data.question_list[i].answer;
          questions[i]["correct_description"] = data.question_list[i].correct_description;
          questions[i]["incorrect_description"] = data.question_list[i].incorrect_description;
          questions[i]["correct_comment"] = data.question_list[i].correct_comment;               //**********************
          questions[i]["incorrect_comment"] = data.question_list[i].incorrect_comment;           //************************
        }


    });

    $("#start_quiz").on("click", function(){

        $("#your_score").html("YOUR SCORE: " + score + " OUT OF " + number_of_question);

        current_question = questions[current_question_number];
        
        if (current_question["annotation"] != "" && flag == 0){
            var question_html = "<p><b>Question " + current_question["question_number"] + " of " + number_of_question + "</b></p><br>";
            question_html += "<p>" + current_question["annotation"] + "</p>";
            
            $("#quiz_part").html(question_html);

            $("#submit_button_div").html("<button id='annotation_continue' style='background-color:#F6761D; color:#FFF; padding:3px 13px; font-weight:bold; border:2px solid #cccccc; margin-right:15px;'>Click to Continue</button>");
        }else{
            flag = 0;
            var question_html = "<p><b>Question " + current_question["question_number"] + " of " + number_of_question + "</b></p><br>";
            question_html += "<p><span style='color: red;'>" + current_question["type"] + "</span>  " + current_question["question"] + " <b>" + current_question["instruction"] + "</b></p><br>";
            for (m = 0; m<current_question["choice"].length; m++){
                question_html += "<p> <input type='radio' name='choice' value='" + current_question["choice"][m]["label"] + "'> <span class='radio-content'>" + current_question["choice"][m]["option"] + "</span></p>";
            }

            $("#quiz_part").html(question_html);

            $("#submit_button_div").html("<button id='submit_answer' style='background-color:#F6761D; color:#FFF; padding:3px 13px; font-weight:bold; border:2px solid #cccccc; margin-right:15px;'>SUBMIT</button>");
        }

    });
    
    $("#submit_button_div").on('click', '#annotation_continue', function(){
        flag = 1;
        continue_button();
    });
//  $("#submit_answer").on("click", function(){
    $("#submit_button_div").on('click', '#submit_answer', function(){
        //current_question_number++;

        var answer = current_question["answer"];
        var correct_desc = current_question["correct_description"];
        var incorrect_desc = current_question["incorrect_description"];

        var correct_comment = current_question["correct_comment"];             //************************
        var incorrect_comment = current_question["incorrect_comment"];          //************************

        var checked_answer = $("input[name='choice']:checked").val();

        if (!checked_answer){
            //$( "#no_check" ).dialog("open");

            dialog = $("#no_check").dialog({
                //width: 'auto', // overcomes width:'auto' and maxWidth bug
                maxWidth: 200,
                height: 'auto',
                modal : true,
                open: function(event, ui) {
                    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
                },
                buttons: {
                    'OK': function () {
                        agreed = true;
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                beforeClose: function () {
                    return agreed;
                }
            });

            dialog.dialog("open");

        }else if(checked_answer == answer){
            current_question_number++;
            //autoOpen : false,
            score++;
            // submit the new score to server
            $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url: progress_url,
              data: { a01_userid: userid, userProgress: score }
            });
            
            $("#your_score").html("YOUR SCORE: " + score + " OUT OF " + number_of_question);

            $(".correct_content").html("<span style='color:green; font-family:Calibri;'>" + correct_desc + "</span> " + correct_comment);  //*****************************
            $("#correct").dialog({              
                width: dialogWidth,
                height: 'auto',
                position: {my: "center", at: "center", of: window},
                modal : true,

                open: function(event, ui) {
                    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
                },
                buttons: [
                {
                   text: "Continue",
                   class: 'correct_button',
                   click: function() {
                      $(this).dialog("close");
                   }
                }
                ],
                beforeClose: function () {
                    continue_button();
                }

            }).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("color","green");
            $("#correct").dialog("open", "position",  {my: "center", at: "center", of: window});

        }else{
            current_question_number++;
            $(".incorrect_content").html("<span style='color:red; font-family:Calibri;'>" + incorrect_desc + "</span> " + incorrect_comment);           //****************
            $("#incorrect").dialog({
                width: dialogWidth,
                height: 'auto',
                position: {my: "center", at: "center", of: window},
                modal : true,

                open: function(event, ui) {
                    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
                },
                buttons: [
                {
                   text: "Continue",
                   class: 'incorrect_button',
                   click: function() {
                      $(this).dialog("close");
                   }
                }
                ],
                beforeClose: function () {
                    continue_button();
                }
            }).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("color","red");
            $("#incorrect").dialog("open", "position", {my: "center", at: "center", of: window});
        }

    });

    $("#quiz_part").on('click', '#retry_button', function(){
        location.reload(true);
    });

    function continue_button(){
        if (current_question_number == number_of_question){
            var percentage = score / number_of_question;
            var pass = pass_percentage / 100;
            if (percentage >= pass){
                passed();
            }else{
                failed();
            }

            return false;
        }

        current_question = questions[current_question_number];
        
        if (current_question["annotation"] != "" && flag == 0){
            var question_html = "<p><b>Question " + current_question["question_number"] + " of " + number_of_question + "</b></p><br>";
            question_html += "<p>" + current_question["annotation"] + "</p>";
            
            $("#quiz_part").html(question_html);

            $("#submit_button_div").html("<button id='annotation_continue' style='background-color:#F6761D; color:#FFF; padding:3px 13px; font-weight:bold; border:2px solid #cccccc; margin-right:15px;'>Click to Continue</button>");
        }else{
            flag = 0;
            var question_html = "<p><b>Question " + current_question["question_number"] + " of " + number_of_question + "</b></p><br>";
            question_html += "<p><span style='color: red;'>" + current_question["type"] + "</span>  " + current_question["question"] + " <b>" + current_question["instruction"] + "</b></p><br>";
            for (m = 0; m<current_question["choice"].length; m++){
                question_html += "<p> <input type='radio' name='choice' value='" + current_question["choice"][m]["label"] + "'> <span class='radio-content'>" + current_question["choice"][m]["option"] + "</span></p>";
            }

            $("#quiz_part").html(question_html);

            $("#submit_button_div").html("<button id='submit_answer' style='background-color:#F6761D; color:#FFF; padding:3px 13px; font-weight:bold; border:2px solid #cccccc; margin-right:15px;'>SUBMIT</button>");

        }
    }

    function passed(){
        var failed_html = '<div style="width:100%;padding: 1.5vw 0 1vw 0;" class="text-center"> \
        <img src="images/success.png" style="width: 70%"> \
        </div>';


        $("#quiz_part").html(failed_html);
        $("#submit_button_div").html("");
    }

    function failed(){
        var failed_html = '<div style="width:100%;padding: 1.5vw 0 1vw 0;" class="text-center"> \
        <img src="images/failed.png" style="width: 70%"> \
        </div> \
        <div style="width:100%;padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;" class="text-center"> \
        <p class="text-center" style="color:#222222;"><b>';
        failed_html += failed_remark;
        failed_html += '</b></p></div>';

        failed_html += '<div style="width:100%;" class="text-center" id="retry_div"> \
            <button id="retry_button" style="padding:1vw 3vw; background-color: #293155; font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; color:#ffffff;" id="start_quiz">CLICK HERE TO RETRY</button> \
        </div>';

        $("#quiz_part").html(failed_html);
        $("#submit_button_div").html("");
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

when i click on the error on right corner it shows:
var userid = ***@test.in; //which the userid from the database

Comment: Put this `<?php echo $userid ; ?>` in `""`.

Comment: I did, but no change

Comment: did that error gone or not ? 118 line is this `var userid = <?php echo $userid ; ?>;` ?

Comment: No the error is not gone. yes the 118 line is var userid = <?php echo $userid ; ?>;

Comment: When I comment out var userid = <?php echo $userid ; ?>; the program runs fine. without any issue. but I need the userid to get the progress for user and update them in databse

Comment: You need to put that inside quotes i.e `var userid = "<?php echo $userid ; ?>";`

Comment: yes, it works. thank you. there also also another userid in the file was causing the issue which i removed it